# jQuery cycle access data in array and append to div

Tags: jquery, arrays, cycle

I worked up a slightly tricked-out jQuery cycle on my site and I need to load the `data` from the specific slide into a different div which sits on top of the actual slider, so each time I hit next/prev it will load the correct data - my question is in the callbacks how to I set the index so it corresponds to the correct data in my array? I suppose the real question would be about accessing data in an array, not cycle.

```
    var array = [ 
        {
            url: 'slide01.jpg',
            data : 'Eat, <br /> Drink, <br /> Escape!'
        },    
        {
            url: 'slide02.jpg',
            data : 'Eat, <br /> Drink, <br /> Escape!2'
        },  
        {
            url: 'slide03.jpg',
            data : 'Eat, <br /> Drink, <br /> Escape!3'
        },  
        {
            url: 'slide04.jpg',
            data : 'Eat, <br /> Drink, <br /> Escape!4'
        },  
        {
            url: 'slide05.jpg',
            data : 'Eat, <br /> Drink, <br /> Escape!5'
        }                        
    ];

    var path = 'img/';

        $.each(array, function(i) {
            $('#slider').append('<li data-id="' + i + '"><img src=' + path + array[i].url + '></li>');
        });

        $('#slider').cycle({
        fx: "scrollHorz",
        next: "#next",
        prev: "#prev",
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 5000,
        before: onBefore(),
        after: onAfter(),
        cssBefore: {
            opacity: 0
        },
        animIn: {
            opacity: 1
        },
        animOut: {
            opacity: 0
        },
        cssAfter: {
            opacity: 1
        },
        delay: 3000
        });
        function onBefore() { 
        $('#content').html("Scrolling image:<br>" + this.src); 
        } 
        function onAfter() { 
        $('#content').empty().append('<h1>' + array[i].data + '</h1>'); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The after event has the following parameters http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html:

`function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag)`

So you can do something like array[options.currSlide] inside that event..

```
 function onAfter(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) { 
      $('#content').empty().append('<h1>' + array[options.currSlide].data + '</h1>'); 
    }
```